# How can I have different Emacs `org-mode` date time format for a heading and sub-heading?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I'd like to tidy my current workflow practice on `org-mode`.
Each day I check out my `org-mode` agenda which lists appointments
Then I jot down/write a time boxed plan which can then merge with the org-mode agenda which is tidy but not editable.

I should of course just progress my plans for today but am distracted by the possibility that I could write tidier time boxed plans if I could toggle the date-time format in a sub-heading.

How can I display this

- <2022/06/01> Linear Plan

  - <2022/06/01 10:00> Dev org-mode time format
  - <2022/06/01 11:00> Dev design 1
  - <2022/06/01 12:00> Leave for appointment

as this?

- <2022/06/01> Linear Plan

  - <10:00> Dev org-mode time format
  - <11:00> Dev design 1
  - <12:00> Leave for appointment

Comment: How about using the `*Org Agenda*` view combined with the built-in time grid feature?  https://orgmode.org/manual/Time_002dof_002dday-specifications.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't do this, because org-mode requires this specific date/time format and does not support nesting in this way.

But you might want to have a look at [8.2.2 Custom time format](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html#Custom-time-format). This would allow you to toggle the *display* of a custom time format -- but the underlying data still has to be in the required format.

Comment: However, a custom time format is an all-or-nothing deal: you cannot set different custom time formats for different parts of your file (AFAIK).

Comment: Right, it changes the display of all dates.